# Device and app to help sleep

Tags: iphone-app, ipad-app, apple

Some people need some "noise" to fall in sleep, and when they sleep the noise is not needed anymore. I'm wondering if there is any device (e.g., Apple Watch) and app, such that:

1. a person stays in bed and listens to youtube or some audio programs
2. the device can detect if he falls in sleep
3. when he has felt in sleep, the device will close the youtube or audio apps

Could anyone help?

Comment: Not for the Apple :-)  There is for Android,  It hooks to **Tasker**, **IFTTT** and **WebHooks** etc.  Maybe look for support for these apps/services

Comment: To do this, you need to wear a smartwatch in bed. The watch can reliably  detect when you fall asleep. What you need then is an event or a signal that the smartwatch sends to your tablet to which it is usually connected (to send the collected health data to). The tablet can then turn itself off or send another signal to some smart-home device.   ---
Maybe, simply just wait until the tablet turns itself off after playing the podcast, and some subsequent inactivity on your side..